# regex - check string if contains all string from array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have a search that will check if string the contains all strings from the search query. I managed to do it using loops. But how can do it using regex ?

Here my current code.

```
var itemMatches = [];
var itemStr = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
var search = 'dog over  jumps   quick';

// split by spaces,filter to remove empty in array due to double space
var arrStr =  search.split(' ').filter(function(str) { return str });

// check if string exist
for (var i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {

    var text = arrStr[i].toString().toLowerCase();

    if (itemStr.indexOf(text) !== -1) {
        itemMatches.push(true);
    } else {
        itemMatches.push(false);
    } 
}

// if all string exist
if (itemMatches.every(isAllTrue)) {
    // all matched !!
}

// if array all true
function isAllTrue(key) {
    return key;
}
```

Comment: What is `props`?

Comment: This is not something that _should_ be done using regex in the first place, IMHO.

Comment: @Mohammad typo, it is 'search' i mean.

Comment: @misorude Just asking if it's possible. btw. tnx for the opinion mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Turn each word into a lookahead of the form `(?=.*${word})`, and put all lookaheads next to each other, to produce a pattern like `(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)`. Add a `^` to the beginning (to ensure the regex fails quickly on the first character if it's impossible), and pass it to `new RegExp`:

```js
var itemStr = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
var search = 'dog over  jumps   quick';

const toPattern = search => new RegExp(
  '^' + 
  search
    .match(/\S+/g)
    .map(word => `(?=.*${word})`)
    .join('')
);

console.log(toPattern(search).test(itemStr));
console.log(toPattern('dog cat').test(itemStr));
```

Note that if any of the non-whitespace characters contain characters with a *special meaning* in a regular expression, like `^`, `$`, `(`, and so on, you'll have to escape them first:

```
const escape = str => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
const toPattern = search => new RegExp(
  '^' + 
  search
    .match(/\S+/g)
    .map(escape)
    .map(word => `(?=.*${word})`)
    .join('')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all word in string use and use `.every()` to check that all item return `true`

```js
var itemStr = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
var search = 'dog over  jumps   quick';

var res = search.match(/\S+/g).every(function(val){
  return itemStr.indexOf(val) > -1;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks mate! it work! one thing to do is convert itemStr and val to lowercase.

Comment: @WarrenClarin Glad to help you. So you need to use `.toLowerCase()` http://jsfiddle.net/ru3ec5hd/